# Groovy 4, JDK 11: Caught: Assertion failed

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I mimic code snippet at reference document at https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_groovydoc_comment

Program

```
print 'hello'

/**@
 * FFF
 */
class Oho {
    /**@
     * KKK
     */
    void run() {
    }
}

assert Oho.class.groovydoc.content.contains('FFF')
assert Oho.class.getMethod('run', new Class[0]).groovydoc.content.contains('KKK')
```

[image]

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51991,suspend=y,server=n -Dgroovy.home=C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0 -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\conf\groovy-starter.conf -javaagent:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-4.0.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --conf C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\conf\groovy-starter.conf --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --classpath .;C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\groovy_projects\proj2022\out\production\proj2022;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\ant-1.10.12.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\ant-antlr-1.10.12.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\ant-junit-1.10.12.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\ant-launcher-1.10.12.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\commons-cli-1.5.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\gpars-1.2.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-ant-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-astbuilder-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-cli-commons-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-cli-picocli-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-console-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-contracts-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-datetime-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-dateutil-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-docgenerator-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-ginq-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-groovydoc-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-groovysh-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-jmx-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-json-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-jsr223-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-macro-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-macro-library-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-nio-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-servlet-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-sql-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-swing-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-templates-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-test-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-test-junit5-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-testng-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-toml-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-typecheckers-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-xml-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\groovy-yaml-4.0.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\ivy-2.5.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jackson-annotations-2.13.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jackson-core-2.13.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jackson-databind-2.13.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jackson-dataformat-toml-2.13.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jansi-2.4.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\javaparser-core-3.24.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jcommander-1.78.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jline-2.14.6.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jquery-3.5.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\jsr166y-1.7.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-4.13.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\mxparser-1.2.2.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.3.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\qdox-1.12.1.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\snakeyaml-1.28.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\testng-7.5.jar;C:\dovy\tools\groovy-4.0.0\lib\xstream-1.4.18.jar --encoding=UTF-8 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\groovy_projects\proj2022\src\sample\Auto.groovy --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51991', transport: 'socket'
helloDisconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51991', transport: 'socket'
Caught: Assertion failed: 

assert Oho.class.groovydoc.content.contains('FFF')
                 |         |       |
                 |         ''      false
                 groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc$1@682c1e93 (toString() == "")

Assertion failed: 

assert Oho.class.groovydoc.content.contains('FFF')
                 |         |       |
                 |         ''      false
                 groovy.lang.groovydoc.Groovydoc$1@682c1e93 (toString() == "")

    at Auto.run(Auto.groovy:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix error?

Comment: Have you enabled it with `-Dgroovy.attach.runtime.groovydoc=true` as it says in the docs?

Comment: The notice should place before code snippet in reference document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank [@tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509/tim-yates), Set VM option

```
-Dgroovy.attach.runtime.groovydoc=true
```

[image]